# How to select the first lines of a BSON file

Tags: mongodb, file, extract, bson

I have a giant BSON file (100GB) on a linux server that I want to import in **MongoDB**. 
To test the importation, I would like to create a file with the 1000 first lines/tuples of the BSON file.

Would you know how to extract the 1000 first lines into a another BSON file ?

Thanks !

Comment: Depending on what you want to test, just do a dd and copy the first 20 megs to another file and import that file.  The very last document will have been truncated and will fail insert though.

Comment: Alright ! It worked ! We thought that it would fail the entire export. 
Thanks dnlbmn !

Comment: posted an answer reflecting exactly the question you asked if there was something special about wanting to test 1000 documents and proving there are no errors if you're in a CI pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize the above comment doesn't solve the problem you asked.

If you really wanted to carve the "first 1000", I'd probably still toss it through mongo

```
dd if=/path/to/your/file.bson of=/path/to/your/small.bson bs=1M count=20
```

import that 20Meg file that hopefully has more than 1000 documents in it (if not increase the dd size).

grab the 1000th object ID

```
db.col.find({},{_id:1}).sort({_id:-1}).skip(999).limit(1)
```

that will give you an object ID to use later.

Then use mongodump command to export exactly 1000 documents

ref:https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/

```
mongodump --db YOUR_DB --collection YOUR_COL --query '{_id:{$lte:ObjectId("THE_ID_FROM_LAST_STEP")}}'
```